# online documentation for old versions of nose

Tags: python, nose

**The Question**

Where can I access the documentation for legacy versions of the nose testing framework?

**Why**

I have to support some python code that must run against python 2.6 on a Centos 6 system.  It is clear from experimentation that nosetests --failed does not work on this system.  I'd like to know if I'm just missing a module or not.  More generally, I need to know what capabilities of nose that I have grown used to I will have to do without, *without* having to check for them individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could browse archive.org for the old results. Here's an example of a snapshot from 2012 (near the beginning of archive.org's records for the current site url): https://web.archive.org/web/20120731114655/http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest

Comment: ah right.  Forgot all about archive.org.  I'm marking this the answer.  I should say, however, that this solution is, well, stinky (yes, that was intentional).  I have to guess about the date to version mapping and use a 3rd party site (archive.org).  Perhaps the nose devs don't realize that their releases will be etched in stone and become legacy...  Python documentation can be directly accessed by version number, and the nose documentation needs to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to upgrade nosetests via pip, while still staying with python 2.6. At least, nose 1.3.4 (latest as of this writing) installs cleanly inside the py2.6 virtualenv I just threw together. I don't have any py2.6-compatible code to hand to show that it's working correctly, though.

Comment: This is great information, which will probably help a lot of people.  It doesn't help me, because I am not allowed to so update this server (it involves legacy stuff that is far beyond my control).